# Dual boot Ubuntu does not turn on after loading screen

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

My laptop is using Windows 10 with dual boot Ubuntu 20.04

The dual boot Ubuntu does not turn on after the loading screen (with Ubuntu loading symbol and Asus logo).

In the last time I used it, I reduced the screen light, used almost every last memory, and I let a simulation run overnight.

What might be the problem in my case?

Comment: Can you boot recovery mode, to terminal? And recovery menu offers several choices. Or a video issue, what video card/chip does your system have? Is brightness still turned down?

Comment: Hello @oldfred, thank you for your reply, yes I used the recovery menu and the solution is to update and upgrade the packages. After that everything worked well again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the problem is I havent update and upgrade packages for a while so the screen did not turn on.

The solution is to access ubuntu with recovery mode and use the root shell there to update and upgrade packages (make sure that you have enough space).